# How to create a sqlite table from a python class?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'd like to create a function `makeTable` to create a sqlite table from a python class. I have this class:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a
        self.b
        self.c
```

I tried defining the function in this way:

```
def makeTable(obj):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlfilename)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sqlString)
```

But I have to create the `sqlString` such as:

```
"""CREATE TABLE foo (a text, b text)"""
```

How can I create this `sqlString` automatically from a given class?

Comment: Use an ORM, like [sqlalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/)?

Comment: @marcos-da-silva-sampaio, alecxe does not ask if you use one, but asks if you shouldnt use one as sqlalechmy does this job

Comment: Thanks. I didn't knew the OMR. I will try it to solve the question.

Comment: its `ORM` for [Object Relational Mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) a tool that does what you expect ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alecxe was not really asking a question, but proposes you to use an ORM like [SqlAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/). Your approach is quite too simple and limited. In real live you have to figure out, which data type a column should have, which attributes/properties should go to the database and many other details. An ORM will do that for you and SqlAlchemy is the best one in my opinion.

I case you think that you're happy with a simpler solution, you have to describe that simple solution to us. Or even better: Show some code you wrote and which did not work.

Comment: do you mean `In a real life`?